# Simple_Form multiple rows of several input with single label at top

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I have a nested table associated with my form, so I have a new recipe form and nested ingredients.  Im trying to convert my form to use simple_form and trying to make it so there is a single label for the fields and the fields are inline (I have javascript button to add more lines of ingredients if needed)

EDIT:

So got rid of the labels in simple_form and got it to mostly work but now I cant get it to add the new rows as rows and instead puts it as a single column. Heres my code:

```
<table>
    <tr>
      <th>Ingredient Name</th>
      <th>Info (sliced,minced,etc)</th>
      <th>Amount</th>
      <th>Unit</th>
    </tr>
    <%= f.fields_for :recipe_ingredients do |builder| %>
      <%= render 'recipe_ingredient_fields', f: builder %>
    <% end %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= link_to_add_fields "Add Ingredient", f, :recipe_ingredients,"", "Add a new Ingredient" %></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The ingredient partial:

```
<tr>
  <td><%= f.input :ingredient, label: false %></td>
  <td><%= f.input :info, label: false %></td>
  <td><%= f.input :format_amount, label: false %></td>
  <td><%= f.input :unit, label: false %></td>
  <td><%= f.input :_destroy, as: :hidden, label: false %></td>
  <td><%= link_to "Remove", '#', :onclick => h("remove_fields(this)"), class: "btn", title: "Remove Ingredient", remote: true %></td>
</tr>
```

And the javascript code:

```
function add_fields(link, association, content){
    var new_id = new Date().getTime();
    var regexp = new RegExp("new_" + association, "g");
    $(link).before(content.replace(regexp, new_id));
}
```

This adds it in but all the fields in the first column...I know I need to adjust the before line but not sure what to put to select the row and not the element

Answer (score 0):

From what I read it seems you want some soft of tabular form (read in a table), if that's the case you can build the table using normal html and use `f.input_field` instead of `f.input` this method will give you the field alone, without the rest of the HTML: wrappers, etc.

Do you want this? The wrapper HTML is also used to display errors, hints, etc. How are errors going to display? You can still use `f.input`, inside a cell, you might just want to try it.